# Is there a different fastboot command for the Google Pixel and the oem-off-mode command?

Tags: charging, fastboot, power-on, google-pixel

I'm trying to set a Google Pixel to boot when the power is connected. I found discussion of using the `fastboot oem-off-mode charge = 0` command, but when I reboot the device into the bootloader and try the command I get a `fastboot: usage: unknown command oem-off-mode` error.

Is this command no longer supported or did they rename the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a hyphen in the wrong spot. The proper command is `fastboot oem off-mode-charge = 0`

Answer (score 0):

Try `fastboot oem off-mode-charge 0` (without equal sign) instead.